# How to predict future position of body in solar system?

Tags: physics, movement-prediction, orbit, spaces, position

I have a solar system where each body interacts with each other by force F = G*m1*m2/R^2

Is it possible to predict future position of some random body after t seconds since bodies velocity and position measurement?

I guess, it is possible only with numerical methods, but how to to it fast without calculating system state for each future frame? I don't need a big precise, just a rough estimation to target into sphere of influence of planet.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. But the exact math eludes me. Perhaps https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ can provide a better answer to this question than we could.

Comment: [The three (or more) body problem is notoriously chaotic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem), with only a few predictable solutions. If your your star dominates and you can neglect interactions between planets, then you can run them on Kepler orbit "rails". That's a good approximation for the motion of the planets in our solar system, for instance. [We have past Q&A about how to do that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=kepler). If you need 3+ bodies all interacting strongly then short timesteps are your best bet. Can you clarify which direction you want to go?

Comment: I can't use kepler's orbit. I want different types of systems: double stars, two-three bodies with same mass, etc

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130327/discussion-on-question-by-robotex-how-to-predict-future-position-of-body-in-sola).